# Upload/Download attachments flow using DDD and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design, onedrive, cqrs

I'm designing Agreements system. Each agreement can have multiple attachments and I want to achieve it in Restful and DDD manners.

```
public class Agreement : AggregateRoot 
{
   public Guid Id { get; }
   public Salary Salary { get; private set; } //Value object
   public IReadonlyCollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; } //Entities
}

public class Attachment: Entity
{
   public Guid Id { get;  } //system id
   public string FileName { get; private set; } 
   public string ExternalId { get; } // Points to one drive blob storage
}
```

Flow:

1. Attachments will be uploaded with a separate endpoint POST /attachments where it returns response with one drive recent attachment Id (externalId) to UI client.
2. Each attachment id (externalId) is appended to POST /agreements body for creating agreement itself together with attachments.

Pros:

- agreement endpoint only accept JSON body instead of having multipart with json and bytes array of files, that makes more RESTful and less complicated to clients
- performance gains, there is no need to upload collection file during one main request, instead of that each press on file upload in UI will trigger file to be uploaded before creating agreement.

Cons:

- Some orphan attachments will appear so background CRON job for clearing them needs to be implemented.
- Create no longer atomic as it consists of two steps in a agreement flow.

Question:
Is it fine that Attachment entity is created later then file itself is uploaded. Also It makes issue when clean cron is triggered - during orphan attachments fetching I can't load only attachment but together with Agreement. But by using CQRS I can introduce special read model only for attachments (event though repositories are not allowed for entities).

Comment: How does "Some orphan attachments will appear" happen? How does the system know that all attachments for an agreement are received?

Comment: @Kit for example, user is in agreement form and uploads attachment, it yet not assigned to any agreement (only when agreement is created and attachment ids are passed to create request body) if a user decides stop completing agreement creation, attachment becomes orphan.